# Enabling "last accessed files" feature for only some selected directories?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management

I want to enable "last access timestamps". But not for every files in my PC, because it is unneeded and may cause slowness. Can i enable this feature for only selected directories or files?

Actually, what i really want is automatically deleting some files ~1 minute after accessing them. The reason is that, i will upload many pictures time to time and i dont want to upload same image twice. It has to be deleted from my upload folder after i uploaded it once.

Answer (score 2):

Such setting effects the complete system. You can't enable it only for a few folders.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for your answer but maybe there is an alternative way to achieve same goal. Well, at least I still hope to find a third party program for this.